# Do padding and dilation influence the amount of FLOPs in convolutional layer?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

To my best knowledge, only output size, kernel size, number of input channels, number of output channels and batch size influence the amount of FLOPs in a convolutional layer.

But some people told me that padding and dilation also influence the FLOPs.

Is it true? If it is true, why?

Answer (score 2):

Padding directly changes the input size, so the kernel must convolve with the larger number of input values, which results in more FLOPs.

Dilation is more interesting: the number of operations does not change as you increase it. However, convolutional kernel becomes larger and less operations fit to the input. So, the number of FLOPs  goes down. In this sense, dilation is a counterpart of padding.

You can see how padding and dilation params changes the number of MACC (multiple-accumulate = 2FLOPs) using [Netscope CNN analyzer](http://dgschwend.github.io/netscope/#/editor).

For instance, the default configuration:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Input"
  top: "data"
  input_param { 
    shape: { dim: 1 dim: 3 dim: 227 dim: 227 } 
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 3
  }
}
```

is estimated to have 131.22M MACCs. With `pad: 1` ('same' padding) it is 133.56M. With `dilation: 2` only it becomes 128.9M. But if you compensate the dilation by padding:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Input"
  top: "data"
  input_param { 
    shape: { dim: 1 dim: 3 dim: 227 dim: 227 } 
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 3
    dilation: 2
    pad: 1
  }
}
```

it is again 131.22M.